# How to caching query with Data Import Handler in solr?

Tags: caching, optimization, solr, dataimporthandler

I'm using solr 5.3.1 with Data Import Handler. I have data-config.xml:

```
<entity name="x" query="select * from x">
    <entity name="y1" query="Select * FROM y WHERE y.id='${x.id}' AND y.value=1">...</entity>
    <entity name="y2" query="Select * FROM y WHERE y.id='${x.id}' AND y.value=2">...</entity>
    <entity name="y3" query="Select * FROM y WHERE y.id='${x.id}' AND y.value=3">...</entity>
    ...
    <entity name="y4" query="Select * FROM y WHERE y.id='${x.id}' AND y.value=n">...</entity>
<entity>
```

You can see query **"Select * FROM y WHERE y.id='${x.id}'"** is duplicate and that will query many time.
There are any way to optimize ?
Thanks